# Sending UTF-8 message to JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, utf-8

I want to send a message to a JSF page with `UTF-8` format, but the `<p:message>` doesn't show correct characters.
I'm using Tomcat 8.0.28, JSF 2 and Spring.
JSF page:

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
     <p:messages id="messages" style="color:red;margin:8px;" autoUpdate="true"/>
     <p:outputLabel value="Username:"/>
     <p:inputText id="usernameInput" value="#{userMgmtBean.username}"/>
     <p:outputLabel value="Password:"/>
     <h:inputSecret id="passwordInput" value="#{userMgmtBean.password}"/>
     <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{userMgmtBean.authenticate}"/>
</h:form>
```

java Bean method:

```
public String authenticate(){

    String username = this.username;
    String password = Hash.createHash(this.password);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if(username != null && password != null && !username.equals("")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            if (users.get(i).getUsername().equals(username) && users.get(i).getPassword().equals(password)) {
                Timestamp lastLogin = users.get(i).getLastLogin();
                int numberOfLogin = users.get(i).getNumberOfLogin();

                users.get(i).setNumberOfLogin(++numberOfLogin);
                users.get(i).setLastLogin(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
                service.update(users.get(i));

                context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("username", username);
                context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("numberOfLogin", numberOfLogin);
                context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("lastLogin", lastLogin);
                return "/pages/Home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
            }
        }
    }

    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه است!"));
    return null;
}
```

And this is what I get:
`��� �����? ?� ��� ���� ������ ���!`

I also guess that the problem is about `FacesContext` not  `<p:message>`

**I've tried these solutions before:**
[How to set JSF message encoding to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245835/how-to-set-jsf-message-encoding-to-utf-8)
[i18n with UTF-8 encoded properties files in JSF 2.0 appliaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645491/i18n-with-utf-8-encoded-properties-files-in-jsf-2-0-appliaction/3646601#3646601)
[UTF-8 encoding of GET parameters in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996205/utf-8-encoding-of-get-parameters-in-jsf)
But Nothing !!!

Comment: You seem to be sending a string which is hardcoded in a Java class instead of retrieved from a properties file. Is that Java class itself saved using UTF-8? Is that Java class itself read using UTF-8? What if you replace that hardcoded message by this string? `"\u0646\u0627\u0645 \u06A9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u06CC \u06CC\u0627 \u0631\u0645\u0632 \u0639\u0628\u0648\u0631 \u0627\u0634\u062A\u0628\u0627\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062A\!"`

Comment: @BalusC I don't know how I can check the java class format and I replace your string, but it didn't work. By the way thanks for your suggestion

Comment: actually I removed the last "\" and it worked ! Is there any way to change my string to yours dynamically?

Comment: You'd better fix the editor, compiler/builder and runtime to use UTF-8 over all place. Then you can just continue writing Arabic in your source files (although the better practice is to put localized text in resource bundle files and then use `ResourceBundle` API to obtain them, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13655540). First step, which editor are you using? If Eclipse, check if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19169136

Comment: @balusc Thank you so much, I changed the editor setting and my problem solved. I'm using Intellij IDEA 14. The path of this setting is: File -> Settings -> Editor -> File encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as BalusC mentioned, editor's encoding is the problem. In case of Intellij IDEA solution is:

`File -> Settings -> editor -> File encoding`